# GNU make: Can I delete obsolete files?

Tags: matlab, makefile

In my workflow, I have lots of `xxx.smr` files in a folder and I need to convert them into other file format `xxx_step3.mat` by importing some data from `xxx_info.xlsx`. I learned that GNU make is powerful in keep all the files up-to-date.

In a very simple "explicit" format (without sophisticated wild card usage), Makefile for this process would look like this. To handle multiple `xxx.smr` files and their descendants, I should be able to do that by modifying this file.

```
   .PHONY: all clean
   all: xxx_step3.mat
   xxx_step3.mat: xxx_step2.mat xxx_info.xlsx
       matlab -r "merge2files('xxx_step2.mat', 'xxx_info.xlsx')"
   xxx_step2.mat: xxx_step1.mat 
       matlab -r "convertmat('xxx_step1.mat')"
   xxx_info.xlsx: master.xslx
       matlab -r "extractfromMasterxlsx('master.xlsx', 'xxx_info.xlsx')"
   xxx_step1.mat: xxx_step0.smr 
       @echo "\nCreate " $@
   # I can't do this step from the command line so I leave message
   clean:
       rm -f xxx_step1.mat xxx_step2.mat xxx_step3.mat xxx_info.xlsx
```

However, I realized that, when some of `xxx.smr` files were found to be surplus and deleted at some point, running GNU make with this Makefile does not delete the obsolete descendant files, including all the intermediate files and the final `xxx_step3.mat` files, that are dependent on those deleted `xxx.smr` files.

For example, I start with the three `xxx.smr` files and run Make.

```
A.smr, B.smr, C.smr
```

It will create all the descendants, including the final target files:

```
A_step3.mat, B_step3.mat, C_step3.mat
```

Later, say, I find the `B.smr` contained a fatal error and decided to delete from the folder.

```
A.smr, C.smr
```

Running Make at this stage will result in ... no change, because both `A_step3.mat` and  `C_step3.mat` are newer than its direct prerequisites (and than `A.smr`  and `C.smr`). However, actually I need to remove all the descendants of `B.smr`, such as `B_step1.mat`, `B_step2.mat`, `B_step3.mat`, and `B_info.xlsx`. If those obsolete files are kept, the final target `B_step3.mat` will be included in the subsequent analyses and affect the results.

I wonder if there is a "smart" way of removing `xxx_step1.mat`, `xxx_step2.mat`, `xxx_step3.mat`, `xxx_info.xlsx` files, when their corresponding `xxx.smr` files have been deleted.

Or should I just implement this with MATLAB or Python etc?

Comment: If you noticed, under `clean:` you have the simple shell command `rm` to remove the unwanted files. You can add `*.smr` to the `rm` list and they will be deleted on `make clean`. Since the `Makefile` contains simple shell commands, instead of removing `*.smr`, you could also test and remove the others before removing teh `smr` file with a for loop. e.g. `for i in *.smr; do for j in ${i%%_*}_step?.mat; do rm "$j"; done; done`

Comment: You would add a similar `rm` for the `_into.xlsx` files.

Comment: You can also declare certain file names as intermediates, in which case `make` will just delete them as it goes along, if that's what you want. Can you explain a bit better what kind of behaviour you want?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I tried to improve the clarity of the scenario by adding examples. `for` loop is powerful, but maybe it is how to find out that `B.smr` has been deleted while `B_step?.mat` are still present. It is rather easy to do in MATLAB or Python.

Answer (score 1):

Since a `Makefile` is a collection of shell commands, on your `clean:` target, you can collect and remove all the files that correspond to your `xxx.smr` files using a `for` loop and **parameter expansion/substring matching**. To find all files that correspond to each `xxx.smr` file, find all `xxx.smr` files. Then for each `xxx.smr`, extract `xxx` and remove all `xxx_step?.*` and `xxx_info.*` files. After each of the `step?` and `info` files are removed, then remove `xxx.smr`. In multi-line form it would look like:

```
for i in *.smr; do 
    for j in ${i%.*}; do 
        rm -f "${j}_step?.*" "${j}_info.*"
    done
    rm -f "$i"
done
```

Or, in a single line:

```
for i in *.smr; do for j in ${i%.*}; do rm -f "${j}_step?.*" "${j}_info.*"; done; rm -f "$i"; done
```

**Note** this will remove all `xxx_step...` and `xxx_info...` files for each `xxx.smr` file. Make sure this is what you intend and run on a test directory first. You can tighten the extensions above to just remove `xxx_info.xlsx` by replacing `xxx_info.*` with `xxx_info.xlsx`, etc...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. I was not aware of the power of shell commands. But maybe I was not clear enough. See the examples above. I need to first find out (1) which `xxx.smr` has been deleted from the folder, then (2) which descendant files should be deleted, and (3) how to delete them. (1) is kind of similar to what make is good about, but in a sort of opposite way.